# Spider-Man comic with him complaining about New York

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man

Looking for a comic with Spider-Man riding in or on a cab or car (holiday theme as well). He's had a terribly stressful day and asks, "God why do you hate New Yorkers?"

Late 80s early 90s?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be [*Web of Spider-Man* issue #28](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_28), from 1985:

[image: Page from "Web of Spider-Man" issue 28]